# Select choices on form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django form which takes a CHOICE tuple:

```
ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE = (
    (1, 'Lion'),
    (2, 'Tiger'),
    (3, 'Dolphin'),
    (4, 'Shark'),
)

class AnimalInfoForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    animal_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE,
    )
```

What I want to do though, is offer a different choice selection based on named url patterns.

So in my view I I have something like this:

```
 def AnimalInfo(request, environment=None):
      ...
```

What I need help with is offering different choice options depending on the `environment` variable. For example:

```
 def AnimalInfo(request, environment=None):
      ...
     if environment == 'marine':
         # only offer choices 3,4
         ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE = (
             (3, 'Dolphin'),
             (4, 'Shark'),
         )
```

How can I dynamically configure the choices like this based on the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically modify the choices in the form init by passing the environment variable to the form:

views.py

```
form = AnimalInfoForm(environment)
```

forms.py

```
ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE = (
    (1, 'Lion'),
    (2, 'Tiger'),
    (3, 'Dolphin'),
    (4, 'Shark'),
)

ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE_AFRICA = (
    (1, 'Lion'),
    (2, 'Tiger'),
    (3, 'Elephant'),
    (4, 'Monkey'),
)

class AnimalInfoForm(forms.Form):
    animal_type = forms.Field()
    def __init__(self, environment, *args, **kwargs):
       super(AnimalInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       if environment == "Africa":
           self.fields['animal_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE_AFRICA))
       else:
            self.fields['animal_type'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ANIMAL_TYPE_CHOICE))
```

Comment: Is it important to keep the `animal_type = forms.Field()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the choices attribute of your form field widget.